# sql - How do I add child of child when dependent on parent

Tags: sql, logic

I'm building a wpf application which interacts with a sql database.

I'm confused about adding children of children in my window.

For example.. I just created a fishing trip so my fishing trip doesnt have a primary key yet.

I add fishes in the window which when saved will get assigned the primary key of the fishing trip.

But I also want to add users to each of the fishes.

When I create these users (many to one relationship with fishes), i can't assign them the primary key of the fishes because I have not saved to database because I don't have a fishing trip primary key.

So when I save, how do I go down the hierarchy past the first level?

Comment: 1) Don't transactions allow you to make "multiple assignments" like this as long as the final state post-transaction is valid? 2) Does it really make logical sense for every fish to be part of a single fishing trip, and part of a single user? None of those relationships sounds intuitively correct to me.

Comment: There might have been some confusion in my explanation of the relationships. One trip can have many fishes and one fish can have many users.

Comment: It seems backwards to me that a fish can have many users. What are you attempting to model with your data?

Comment: However you're doing this, "I add fishes in the window which when saved will get assigned the primary key of the fishing trip." wouldn't you repeat the same thing for each fish as you add the users?

Answer (score 1):

When you save, just do things in the right order and wrap the whole lot in a Transaction.

- Begin the Transaction.
- Insert the "Fishing Trip" record.  Retrieve the Primary Key for the record just inserted.
- For each User:
- - Create each "Trip-User" record.  Use the Trip's Primary Key.
- - Retrieve the Primary Key for the "Trip-User" record just added.
- - For each User:
- - - Create the "Trip-User-Fish" record(s).  Use the Primary Keys from the Trip and the Trip-User records.
- Commit the Transaction.